# Add specific hardcoded values to some rows in a computed column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, calculated-columns

Is there a possibility to change some values of a computed column? We need it because the values are connected to another system and three of them have to be changed.

Our computed column looks like this:

```
('Product-'+CONVERT([NVARCHAR](100),(1000)+[Id],(0)))
```

I now have to change the values `Product-1356`, `Product-1655` and `Product-1701` to `Product-12`, `Product-17` and `Product-18` (example values). These three have to be hardcoded. The rest has to be computed as it was before.

I've tried updating it normally using T-SQL:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET ProductId = 'Product-12'
WHERE ProductId = 'Product-1356'
```

But now I'm getting the following error:

> The column "ProductId" cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator.

Also updating the `Id` column didn't work because it's the primary key:

> Cannot update identity column 'Id'.

How can I do this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options I can think of:

1. Delete those rows and re-add them with the correct id.
2. Set up a new column of ProductIdOverride and put any hard coded IDs in there. Leave Null when you want the existing formula to be used. Then change your computed column to `COALESCE(ProductIdOverride, ('Product-'+CONVERT([NVARCHAR](100),(1000)+[Id],(0))))`